# Hibernate INSERT not appearing in database "JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, deltaspike

I'm working on the database portion of a project which uses DeltaSpike and Hibernate in Java SE.

All `SELECT` statements work, however no `INSERT` statements appear in the database. There is no warning, error, or exception.

I've gone through the logs for Hibernate and found the following:

```
[DEBUG] [05/05 00:52:16] [org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl] JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only
```

I've tried adding the `@Transactional` annotation from [`javax.transaction`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) and [`org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction`](https://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.9.3/org/apache/deltaspike/jpa/api/transaction/Transactional.html), as well as changing the `autocommit` setting in `persistence.xml`.

How can I get this to stop trying to roll back the transaction?

**persistence.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="primary">
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
      <!-- Omitted for Brevity -->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**ExampleRepository.java**

```java
@Repository(forEntity = ExampleData.class)
public interface ExampleRepository extends EntityRepository<ExampleData, Long> {

}
```

**ExampleListener.java**

```java
@Singleton
public class ExampleListener extends ExampleAdapter {

    private final ExampleRepository emoteRepo;

    @Inject
    public ExampleListener(ExampleRepository exampleRepo) {
        this.exampleRepo = Objects.requireNonNull(exampleRepo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExample(ExampleEvent event) {
            // Omitted for Brevity

            ExampleData exampleData = new ExampleData(exampleId, parentId);
            exampleRepo.save(exampleData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you try adding the `@Transactional` annotation? Edit the question and show what you tried, so we can better help you figure out what you did wrong. --- Also, where is `EmoteListener` called from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the project, [`@Entity`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) and [`@Table`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/Table.html) were used incorrectly.

The project had the following, but the queries generated were called `ExampleTable`, not `example` which is what was intended.

```java
@Entity(name = "example")
@Table
public ExampleTable {

}
```

The solution was to change it too:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
public ExampleTable {

}
```